# an object with methods in one line

Tags: python, oop, lambda

*I know it is probably totally useless but...*

I was **wondering** if it is possible to create an object with `type()` in one line possibly with use of a `lambda` function.

I want to make a function that **increments** the value of the object:

I am trying following:

```
class thing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
    def inc(self):
        self.val += 1
obj = thing()
```

So i just add a lambda function to the dict and a `()` to the tail of the type:

```
obj = type('thing', (), {'value':0, 'inc': lambda self: self.value+1})()
```

The **problem** here is that the lambda only returns a value, and I don't think I can affect the `value` of `obj`

So my question is this: Can i make a lambda function in a type definition that changes the instance value of the object?

Comment: FWIW, you might be able to use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) instead of writing your own type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setattr`.

```
>>> obj = type('thing',(),{'value':0, 'inc': lambda self: setattr(self, 'value', self.value+1)})()
>>> obj.inc()
>>> obj.inc()
>>> obj.value
2
```

But I would agree that it is totally useless.

Comment: P.S. apologies for the horizontal scrolling needed, but you did ask for it in one line...